# transforming $\sum_{k=1}^n{x^{k+(k+1)+ \dots + n}}$ to a product

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

Can we write this sum as a product of some functions of $x$?

In other words i am trying to find $f_1,\dots,f_r$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^n{x^{k+(k+1)+ \dots + n}} = f_1(x)\dots f_r(x)$ for some $r=r(n)$.

I've searched for this formula but couldn't find much information.

Comment: You can always factor out $x^n$ from each term, but the remaining factor may be irreducible (at least over the rationals)...for example when $n=5$, the polynomial factors as $x^5(x^{10} + x^9 + x^7 + x^4 + 1)$.

Comment: The factorization of these polynomials over the rationals are very irregular. See [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Factor%5BTable%5BSum%5Bx%5ESum%5Bj,%7Bj,k,n%7D%5D,%7Bk,1,n%7D%5D,%7Bn,1,10%7D%5D%5D)

Answer (score 1):

If there is no restrictions on the functions $f_i(x)$ one can arbitrary choose $r-1$ of them and set
$$
f_r(x)=\frac{P(x)}{\prod_{i=1}^{r-1}f_i(x)}.
$$

To make the problem meaningful one may restrict $f_i(x)$ to be polynomials. In this case the fundamental theorem of algebra says that the polynomial in question
$$
P(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n x^{kn-\frac{k(k-1)}2}
$$
can be presented as the product of monomials:
$$
\prod_{i=1}^{\frac{n(n+1)}2}(x-\zeta_i),
$$
where $\zeta_i$ are the (complex) roots of the polynomial. To obtain a product of exactly $r$ polynomials ($1\le r\le \frac{n(n+1)}2$) one can multiply some of these monomials together.